# Creating a loop that checks several tables and counts the results depending on value

Tags: php, mysql

I'm not sure what to do when my if statement is true and how to count each hit.

My code first checks a table to get all the companies that are active.
I then want to go to each table for that company that is active, get the last entry, and count how many values for Status are either not equal to `3(!=3)` or equals `2(==2)`.

I have no problems with this code giving me values from the row for each company but I'm not sure how to count this.

```
// Get a list of active companies
$sql_companyinfo="SELECT Name FROM Company_Info Where Active=True ORDER  BY Name";
$result_companyinfo = mysqli_query($conn, $sql_companyinfo);

// Create variables and Loop for each active Company
while($prop_info = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_companyinfo)) {
    $prop_name = $prop_info["Name"];
    $company_table = ("Company_" . "$prop_name");

    // Query Table and get the last record added
    $result_company = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM $company_table WHERE ID=(SELECT MAX(ID) FROM $company_table)");
    $row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($result_company);
    //Status from Last Row Inserted
    $Row_Status = $row1['Status'];

// This is where I get lost. For each company I need to know how many companies where $Row_Status != 3 or == 2
    if ($Row_Status != '3') {
      // Start with 0 and add 1 for each match
       for($n3 = 0; $array[$n3]; $n3++) {
              $n3_result = $n3;
          }
} elseif ($Row_Status == '2') {
      // Start with 0 and add 1 for each match
        for($e2 = 0; $array[$e2]; $e2++) {
              $e2_result = $e2;
        }
{
echo "ERROR: Could not execute";

    }
    }
}

echo $n3_result;
echo $e2_result;
```

How to creating a loop that checks several tables and counts the results depending on value?

Comment: your posted code itself is wrong after the last for loop

Comment: The last for loop seems to be identical to the prior for loop except the assigned variable. Netbeans doesn't show a syntax issue, can you tell me if I'm on the right path or am I doing this all wrong?

Answer (score 0):

See you can do like this na:-

```
$Row_Status = '2';

if ($Row_Status != '3') {

    echo 'ok1';

}  else {

    if ($Row_Status == '2') {

        echo 'ok2';

    } else {

        echo 'ok3';
    }

}
```